# Why isn't "Column ordering" available in my list settings?

Tags: content-type, column, sorting, settings, ordering

I want to change the column order visible when viewing or editing a list item. I have accessed the "Column ordering" interface via the list settings page on other lists in the past, but it isn't visible in this list's settings.

[image: Column Ordering option in List Settings]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you have Content Type management enabled for the list (if you see a list of content type with the option to add more), the display order of columns is set for each content type. Drill down into one of them and you'll see the option under the list of columns for that content type.

Comment: This worked for me but I still dont understand why Microsoft wouldn't allow you to order columns if they were content types.

Comment: Microsoft allows you to change column order for content types. The reason this setting was hidden is that every content type is supposed to have its own column order. So the list-level column order would make little sense. If "Allow Managing Content Types" is enabled - then you can still change column orders but you have to click on the name of the Content Type for which you are changing the column order. there you will see your "Column order" link.

Answer (score 1):

Change the order of the columns in the list's settings (or the content type)

Answer (score 0):

I think hiding the link is a typical "simplification problem", many Microsoft products suffer from. This is a problem because the alerts about changes in items do report in the underlying column order, not in the content type column order.

You can construct the URL by going to the formEdt.aspx page, e.g. select General Settings, and replace the page URL "ListGeneralSettings" by "formEdt"